# Correct way to define virtual attributes on a Model for the keys in a JSON column in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, metaprogramming

In my rails model I have a JSON column which stores some meta information.
This is to be entered bu the user from a form.

Since the keys of the JSON column are not attributes of the model I cannot use them directly in `form_for` instead I need to define a virtual attribute.

Since this number of virtual attributes could grow to be arbitrarily lengthy I would like to use meta programming to define the attributes.

I did try the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21820599/single-virtual-attribute-definition-for-multiple-fields) however when I use the constant in my model I get an error saying that the constant is undefined. So I added the symbols for the keys in an array directly and iterate over them in the module. When I do this I get an error that says stack level too deep.

Please can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `PostgreSQL` specific columns like `hstore` or `json` simply use [`store_accessor`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store/ClassMethods.html#method-i-store_accessor) instead to generate the accessor methods. *Be aware that these columns use a string keyed hash and do not allow access using a symbol.*

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  store_accessor :my_json_column, [ :key_1, :key_2, key_3 ]
end
```

What it doing under the hood? It has define write\read helper methods:

```
def store_accessor(store_attribute, *keys)
  keys = keys.flatten

  _store_accessors_module.module_eval do
    keys.each do |key|
      define_method("#{key}=") do |value|
        write_store_attribute(store_attribute, key, value)
      end

      define_method(key) do
        read_store_attribute(store_attribute, key)
      end
    end
  end
```

# .....

<sup>[store](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did not know about this. If you do not mind, then please could you tell me which method should be preferred (`store_accessor` or using `define_method` in an iterator) and why?

Comment: you should use methods and macros which provided by the Rails and Rails core lib to avoid any duplication of the core lib methods, the Rails code base has a good test coverage. But your answer also good for education purpose. + 1

Comment: _The good coder can write new code, the ninja coder can make old code work again._

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. I return the attribute as a key of the JSON column and it works fine now.

```
# lib/virtuals.rb
module Virtuals

  %W(key_1 key_2 key_3).each do |attr|
    define_method(attr) do
      self.my_json_column[attr]
    end

    define_method("#{attr}=") do |val|
      self.my_json_column[attr] = val
    end
  end
end
```

In my Model i just need to include that above module and it works fine in the `form_for` and updates correctly as well.